# Removing Certain Nodes

Tags: c++

I created a data bag structure. I read the text of a file and insert each word into a node then increment the count if there identical strings. But my problem is, I only want to output only one string of the identical strings and the number of times it was used. But whenever I use my remove function, it removes everything in my file, and if I don't use it, I get the output shown below. I dont know what I am doing wrong, is there a way I don't output duplicate strings?

```
ofstream output;
struct  BagNode
{
    string dataValue;
    string dataCopy;
    int dataCountCopy;
    int dataCount;
    BagNode * next;
};
class Bag{
private:

BagNode * head;

public:

Bag()
{
    head = NULL;

}
void insert(string v)
{
    if(head == NULL){ //empty list
        head = new BagNode;
        removePunct(v);
        head->dataValue = v;
        transform(v.begin(), v.end(), v.begin(), ::tolower);
        head->dataCopy = v;
        head->next = NULL;

    }
    else
    {
            BagNode * n = new BagNode;      // new node
            removePunct(v);
            n->dataValue = v;
            transform(v.begin(), v.end(), v.begin(), ::tolower);
            n->dataCopy = v;
            BagNode * current = head;           //for traversal
            //current = head;
            n->dataCount = 0;
                if(current->dataCopy > v)
                {                       
                    n->next = head;
                    head = n;
                }
                else{           //mid and tail insert
                    while(current->next && current->next->dataCopy < v)
                    {
                        current = current->next;
                    }
                    n->next = current->next;
                    current->next = n;

                }   

    }
    BagNode * check = new BagNode;
    for(check = head; check->next != NULL; check = check->next) 
    {
        if(check->dataCopy == v)//isSame(check->dataValue, v)) 
        {
            check->dataCount++;
        }

    }

}
 bool remove(string v) //bool
{
    bool status;
    if(head == NULL){
        status = false;
    }
    else if(head->dataCopy > v)
    {//(head->dataValue > v){
        status = false;
    }
    else if(head->dataCopy == v)
    {
        BagNode * t = head;
        head = head->next;
        delete t;
        status = true;
    }
    else//general case
    {
        BagNode * current = head;
        while(current->next && current->next->dataCopy < v){
            current = current->next;
        }
        if(current->next == NULL)
        {
            status = false;
        }
        else if(current->next->dataCopy == v)   //found it
        {
            BagNode *t = current->next;
            current->next = current->next->next;
            delete t;
            status = true;
        }
        else
        {
            status = false;
        }
    }
    return status;
}
void traverse()
{
    BagNode * current;

    current = head;
    while(current)
    {
            output << current->dataValue << " (" << current->dataCount << ")" << " ";
            current = current->next;

    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

> Output: 10Annette (1) 1805 (1) 7 (1) a (1) a (2) a (3) a (4) a (5) a (6) All (1) all (2) an (1) and (1) and (2) and (3) and (4) and (5) and (6) and (10) and (7)

```
if(!inputFile)
    {
        cout << "Could Not Open " << fileName << " File" << endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else
    {
        while(inputFile >> text)
        {
            theBag.insert(text);

        }
        cout << "Processing File Complete" << endl;
        cout << "Please Enter An Output File Name: ";
        getline(cin,outputFilename);
        output.open(outputFilename);
        theBag.traverse();
        theBag.remove(text);
        inputFile.close();
        output.close();
    }
```

Comment: @RawN Ok, its up there. Thanks

Comment: The stupid-simple way that will probably offend the hell out of your instructor is `std::map<std::string, int> strings;` With it you can `strings[stringIJustParsed]++;` and practically all of the work is done. The map will create a new `int` for `stringIJustParsed` and zero initialize it or get a preexisting  `int` if `stringIJustParsed` is already known. New or old `int`, the `int` is incremented and provides your counter.

Comment: @user4581301 so for my dataCount I dont really need it?

Comment: I don't know what you are allowed to get away with in the context of this assignment, but what I'm trying and failing to say is you can discard the entire concept of `Bag` and replace it with a `std::map`.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean now.

Comment: You need to implement this logic: `if (word in bag) increment its count else insert it with count of 1`. Your insert function is doing something very different. You need to change it so rhat it implements this logic.

Comment: @n.m. I have set up where the output is in lexicographical order, I wonder if I can implement that behavior and keep it the way I have it setup

Comment: The answer is yes, the logic is the same logic, you need to insert the new word at a correct place.

Answer (score 1):

If you look here in your insert function you are actually touching every node with that value.  So if `v = "And"` every single "And" word is getting it's data count incremented.  This causes you to get the correct count of a word on every node.

```
for(check = head; check->next != NULL; check = check->next) 
{
    if(check->dataCopy == v)//isSame(check->dataValue, v)) 
    {
        check->dataCount++;
    }
}
```

Seems like you could make your insert a lot simpler with utilizing that behavior.

Comment: If what you're saying is "The best way to not have repeats is to not add duplicates." you're bang on, but your example is missing a chunk of OP's insertion logic.

Comment: Yep, my answer is intentionally not reworking the homework solution.  Thompson already has the inserting figured out they are just a little stuck with debugging why their program is acting the way it is.  Which can be frustrating and I don't recall any classes on debugging ;-)